# Configure SHA-256 Authentication MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to use sha256 authentication MySQL plugin. (MySQL 5.6.10)
Configure the server using the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.6/en/sha256-authentication-plugin.html). 
Added to the file options:

```
[mysqld]
sha256_password_private_key_path=mykey.pem
sha256_password_public_key_path=mykey.pub
```

Server does not start. Get the error:

```
[ERROR] mysqld: unknown variable 'sha256_password_private_key_path=mykey.pem'
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Those variables exist only if your server is built with OpenSSL (as opposite to YaSSL). To confirm whether YaSSL is used you can use command (non-zeroes in output would mean YaSSL):

```
strings /usr/sbin/mysqld |grep -i yassl |wc
```